# Snipping a document that is more than 1 page

Tags: snipping

So when I have a document and it's more than one page that I want to snip, how do I "highlight" the whole document and paste it into a word document, so then I would have it all one page?

Comment: Paste it in and then make the text one or two point sizes smaller until it fits.

Comment: There is an application called Snagit that allows vertical and horizontal screen captures. It is currently $39 but there is a trial version that may satisfy your needs.
https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html